# Suavis vs. dulcis

Tags: word-comparison, adjective

What is the difference between "*[suavis](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=suavis#lexicon)*" and "*[dulcis](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=dulcis#lexicon)*"? Are they synonymous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what Döderlein's [*Handbook of Latin Synonymes*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm) (sic.; tr. Arnold) has to say on these words:

> Suavis; Dulcis. Suavis (ἠΰς) denotes, like ἡδύς, a pleasant odor, and, figuratively that which gives a calm pleasure; dulcis, like γλυκύς, a pleasant flavor, and, figuratively, that which gives a lively pleasure; hence dulcis is a stronger expression than suavis, in Plin. Ep. v. 8, 10. Hæc vel maxima vi, amaritudine, instantia; illa tractu et suavitate, atque etiam dulcedine placet. Plin. H. N. xv. 27. Dulce, et pingue, et suave. (iii. 256.)

Caveat: this is probably too clear-cut of a distinction -- as cmw points out, in actual usage the senses seem to overlap a lot more.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the reference to Döderlein; I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: I'm not really sure Döderlein's delineation holds up in actual usage, even if that is the ultimate origin. Both ἡδύς and *suavis* can refer to taste, and Pliny Maior mentions the *dulcis odor* of Polycnemon. The OLD lists plenty of examples of each for both, too, and in fact places taste first for both.

Comment: @cmw The distinction does seem a bit too neat; I was hesitant to challenge the authority of an illustrious 19C German, but your examples are convincing (and I find that the Britannica thought D's work was "marred by over-subtlety"). Adding a caveat.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are synonyms. They both for example can be contrasted with *amarus* ('bitter').

> quod suave est aliis, aliis fit amarum Lucr. 4.658

> sentit et dulcia et amara Cic. N. D. 3, 13

While they can also both mean 'pleasant' (synonymous with *amoenus* and *iucundus*) where they ostensibly diverge is when *dulcis* means 'friendly' (more synonymous with *amicus*). Lewis and Short don't mention that meaning for *suavis*, and I don't recall an example off-hand that suffices, but we're otherwise splitting a hare's hairs here.

Despite their origins, they *both* can refer to taste and smell. Pliny the Elder for example mentions the *dulcis odor* of Polycnemon. The OLD lists plenty of examples of each for both, too, and in fact places taste first for both.